# Either my file is not being created or read right, Im not sure which

Tags: java, file, io

So in my program I am trying to create a basic .txt file within the project to write/read individual customer objects to. Here is my code for both reading and writing to the file. The program runs with out compilation errors and rights with out throwing an exception but when I try to read the file the program throws "no such file or directory, null" As requested here is all the code for the program as it sits: you get the menu enter 1 to add a customer (that seems to work or so i think) then enter 2 to load and display said customer data that is not working.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;




public class Bank {
    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
     do {
        try {
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
            System.out.println(" Main Menu");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(" Item    Description");
            System.out.println(" ----    --------------------------");
            System.out.println("  1       Creat a new customer");
            System.out.println("  2       View an existing customer");
            System.out.println("  3       Exit the program");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("  Please enter your choice: ");

            int select = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());
            switch ( select ) {
                case 1:
                    createCustomer();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewCustomer();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("\nInvalid selection.");
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } while( true );

}

//----------------------------Main Methods-------------------------------------------\\

public static void createCustomer() {
    try {
        String select;

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("  Create Customer");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

        System.out.print("Customer name: ");
        String customerName = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Customer number: ");
        String customerNum = in.nextLine();

        Customer newCustomer = new Customer( customerName, customerNum);

        System.out.print("Checking account? (y/n): ");
        select = in.nextLine();
        if ( select.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ) {
            System.out.print("\tBalance: ");
            double intBalance = Double.valueOf(in.nextLine());

            Checking newChecking = new Checking("001", intBalance);
            newCustomer.addAccount(newChecking);
        }

        System.out.print("Saving account? (y/n): ");
        select = in.nextLine();
        if ( select.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ) {
            System.out.print("\t    APR: ");
            double apr = Double.valueOf(in.nextLine());

            System.out.print("\tBalance: ");
            double intBalance = Double.valueOf(in.nextLine());

            Savings newSavings = new Savings("002", intBalance);
            Savings.setAnnualPercentageRate(apr);
            newCustomer.addAccount(newSavings);
        }

        System.out.print("Money Market account? (y/n): ");
        select = in.nextLine();
        if ( select.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ) {
            System.out.print("\t    APR: ");
            double apr = Double.valueOf(in.nextLine());
            MoneyMarket.setAnnualPercentageRate(apr);

            System.out.print("Minimum Balance: 1200.00");
            System.out.print("\tBalance: ");
            double intBalance = Double.valueOf(in.nextLine());

            MoneyMarket newMoneyMarket = new MoneyMarket("003", intBalance);
            newCustomer.addAccount(newMoneyMarket);
        }
        Customer.saveCustomer(newCustomer);
        System.out.println(newCustomer.getCustomerDetails());

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void viewCustomer() {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    System.out.println("  View Customer");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    System.out.println(" \nEnter Customer number: ");
    String customerNum = in.nextLine();

    Customer newCustomer = Customer.loadCustomer(customerNum);
    System.out.println(newCustomer.getCustomerDetails());

  }

}

//=====================================================================================\\

interface ITaxable {
  double getTaxesDue();
}

//=====================================================================================\\

abstract class Account {
  private String accountNum;
  private double balance;

public Account(String accountNum, double amount) throws Exception {
    deposit(amount);
    setAccountNum(accountNum);
}

public void setAccountNum(String accountNum) {
    this.accountNum = accountNum;
}

public String getAccountNum() {
    return accountNum;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void deposit(double amount) throws Exception {
    if ( amount < 0){
        throw new Exception("Must enter a deposit greater than 0.");
    }
    else {
        balance += amount;
    }

}

public void withdraw(double amount) throws Exception {
    if ( amount > getBalance() ){
        throw new Exception("Amount exceeds balance.");
    }
    else {
        balance -= amount;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return "Account Number: " + accountNum + ",  Balance: " + balance;
}

}

    //=====================================================================================\\

class Checking extends Account {

    public Checking(String accountNum, double amount) throws Exception {
        super(accountNum, amount);
}

    public void cashCheck(int checkNum, int amount) throws Exception {
        this.withdraw(amount);
}

    public String toString(){
        return "CHK" +getAccountNum()+ "    " +getBalance();
}
}

//=====================================================================================\\

class Savings extends Account implements ITaxable {
  static double annualPercentageRate;

public Savings( String accountNum, double amount ) throws Exception {
    super(accountNum, amount);
}

public static void setAnnualPercentageRate(double annualPercentageRate) throws Exception {
    if ( annualPercentageRate > 0 ) {
        Savings.annualPercentageRate = annualPercentageRate;
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("APR rate must be greater then 0.");
    }
}

public static double getAnnualPercentageRate() {
    return annualPercentageRate;
}

public void addInterest() throws Exception {
    int numberOfDays = 30;
    double interest = getBalance() * numberOfDays * (getAnnualPercentageRate() / 100 / 365);
    deposit(interest);
}

@Override public double getTaxesDue(){ return 0;}

public String toString(){
    return "SAV" +getAccountNum()+ "    " +getBalance();
}


}

 //=====================================================================================\\

class MoneyMarket extends Savings{
   static double miniumBalance = 1200;

public MoneyMarket( String accountNum, double balance ) throws Exception {
    super(accountNum, balance);
    if ( balance < miniumBalance ) {
        throw new Exception("Minimum balance not met.");
    }
}

public static void setMiniumBalance( double amount) throws Exception {
    if ( amount < 0 ){
       throw new Exception("Must enter a amount greater then 0.");
    }
    else {
        MoneyMarket.miniumBalance = miniumBalance;
    }
}

public static double getMiniumBalance() {
    return miniumBalance;
}

@Override
public void withdraw( double amount ) throws Exception {
    if ( getBalance() - amount > miniumBalance ) {
        super.withdraw(amount);
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Amount is greater then minimum balance.");
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return "MMA    " +getAccountNum()+"    "+getBalance();
}

}
 //=====================================================================================\\

class Customer{
private String customerName;
private String customerNum;
private ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

public Customer( String customerName, String cutomerNum) {
    setCustomerName(customerName);
    setCustomerNum(cutomerNum);
}

public void setCustomerName( String customerName ) { this.customerName = customerName; }

public void setCustomerNum( String customerNum ) { this.customerNum = customerNum; }

public String getCustomerName() { return customerName; }

public String getCustomerNum() { return customerNum; }

public void addAccount(Account a) throws Exception {
    if (a != null) {
        accounts.add(a);
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Invalid entry");
    }
}

public static void saveCustomer(Customer c) throws Exception {
    if ( c != null) {
        String fileName = c.customerNum + ".txt";
        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
        output.writeObject(c);
        OutputStream close;

    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Customer does not exist.");
    }

    System.out.println("\nCustomer Saved.");
}

public static Customer loadCustomer(String customerNum) {
    try {
        String fileName = customerNum + ".txt";
        InputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
        ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);
        Customer x = (Customer) input.readObject();
        InputStream close;
        return x;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public String getCustomerDetails() {
    String dets;
    dets = "\nCUSTOMER DETAIL REPORT\n" +
            "-------------------------------------------\n";
    dets += String.format("%s (#%s)\n", this.getCustomerName(),     this.getCustomerNum());
    for (Account a : accounts) {
        dets += String.format("\t%s\n", a);
    }
    return dets;
}

@Override public String toString() { return customerName; }
}

 //=====================================================================================\\
```

Comment: Close or at least flush your streams. Start using try-with-resources which will do it for you.

Comment: is that just outputStream close; and do I need to add that to both input and output or just output

Comment: You should always close your streams (input and output) when you've finished with them otherwise they will not release resources (file handles) back to the system. If the same code keeps running without doing this, you will eventually run out of file handles. and yes outputStream close will flush buffered data to the file

Comment: iv added the input and output stream close; and I still get the same result. I edited the original post to reflect I'm not sure If i did it right

Comment: It isn't clear why it should print anything. Is your file being created? Reads two separate lines? What does that mean? ObjectOutputStreams do not write lines per se. So they do not create ".txt" files. You might have to include a complete example of your code.

Comment: That's my bad. The load file method is called to read in an object then passes it to another method that prints the relivent information associated with the object I just assumed the error was coming from my read and write methods but if those are sound then maybe its in the print method

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Nor can it possibly execute in any way corresponding to what is described here. Please post the real code.